# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar chartsjs en DomPDF y Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, dompdf

Estoy generando unos `PDF` con `DomPDF` y `Laravel`, todo bien para generar.

El inconveniente es que se necesita mostrar gráficos en los `PDF`, y yo nunca había usado esa librería, y me encuentro con la novedad de que no "acepta" `javascript` entonces todo se me fue de las "manos".

estuve intentando usar unas configuraciones que he visto en Internet, pero no me funcionan por eso recurro a este medio, esperando que alguien haya tenido el mismo problema y lo pudo solucionar.

uso [Charjs](https://www.chartjs.org/) para los gráficos.

uso `"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",`

---

Yo se que existen otras librerías pero me gustaría seguir usando `DomPDF`, ya que estoy generando muchos `pdf` y adaptarme a otro que quizás pida cambios, me vendría muy pesado por la cantidad de cosas que tendría que modificar, si existe uno que permita realizar lo que necesito `(graficos)` y se adapte a la forma de trabajar de `dompdf` agradecería me ayuden con un nombre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [Quickchart](https://quickchart.io/documentation/). Dompdf puede renderizar imágenes, y Quickchart te brinda eso, imágenes y trabaja con Chartjs.

Si en Chartjs tienes un gráfico así (Ejemplo de la documentación):

```
{
  type: 'bar',                                // Show a bar chart
  data: {
    labels: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016],   // Set X-axis labels
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Users',                         // Create the 'Users' dataset
      data: [120, 60, 50, 180, 120]           // Add data to the chart
    }]
  }
}
```

Para obtener la imagen con quickchart, simplemente debes hacer:

```
https://quickchart.io/chart?c={type:'bar',data:{labels:[2012,2013,2014,2015,2016],datasets:[{label:'Users',data:[120,60,50,180,120]}]}}
```

Posteriormente, en tu plantilla blade, sólo adjuntas la imagen con la ruta que te brinda quickchart.

```html
<img src="https://quickchart.io/chart?c={type:'bar',data:{labels:[2012,2013,2014,2015,2016],datasets:[{label:'Users',data:[120,60,50,180,120]}]}}">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esa librería puedo resolver lo que son los gráficos.