# Exportar registros a PDF por rangos de Fechas

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Tengo un generador de reportes por rangos de fechas y funciona la perfeccion, el punto es que quiero implementar un exportador de pdf que se genere de acuerdo a las fechas calculadas en 2 input de tipo date, he implementado DomPDF y tambien he hecho unas pruebas con datos en bruto y con una consulta a las base de datos haciendo un all() pero en este caso lo quiero hacer por rangos de fechas, pues no se me ocurre nada. No les pido que me den el codigo de como hacerlo pero si que me orienten, les agradeceria bastante. Dejo mi codigo:

Input:

```
<form action="{{route('ingresos.reportes.resultados')}}" method="POST">
@csrf
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">                            
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" type="date" value="{{old('fecha_ini')}}" name="fecha_ini" id="fecha_ini">      
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" type="date" value="{{old('fecha_fin')}}" name="fecha_fin" id="fecha_fin"> 
            </div>  
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calcular</button>
            </div>                      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controlador para calcular registro de acuerdo a rango:

```
public function reportResult(Request $request){        
    $fi = $request->fecha_ini.' 00:00:00';
    $ff = $request->fecha_fin.' 23:59:59';

    $ingresos = Ingresos::orderBy('date', 'desc')->whereBetween('date', [$fi, $ff])->get();
    $total = $ingresos->sum('monto');
    
    return view('ingresos.reportes.reporte-fecha', compact('ingresos', 'total'));
}
```

Espero haberme dejado entender, y tambien me puedan hechar una mano he buscado por todos lados pero no encuentro una orientacion. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te sirve [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383410/133891) respuesta?

Comment: @JonatanLavado gracias por responder, te comento que no ya que no deseo mostrar graficos solo extraer el contenido que ya a sido consultado por un formulario.

Comment: Primero, te recomiendo leer la [documentación](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). En particular, lo único que necesitas es una plantilla (vista) y una función en tu controlador que genere el PDF.

Comment: @JonatanLavado, ya lei la documentacion. Muchas gracias de todas maneras :)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con el código que muestras?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias por responder, como lo he explciado arriba "Tengo un generador de reportes por rangos de fechas y funciona la perfeccion", **el punto es que quiero implementar un exportador de pdf que se genere de acuerdo a las fechas calculadas en 2 input de tipo date**  asi mismo recalco que no se me ocurre ya que soy principiante, no se me podran orientar. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bueno les comento que logre hacer aquello que les cuestionaba pero haciendo mal uso de las practicas, y es que usando  `onblur="document.getElementById('fecha_fin2').value=this.value"` logre clonar el contenido de un input a otro y dejando como oculto el que tiene el contenido clonado. Claro que estoy haciendo un mal de las practicas pero nose me ocurre nada haber si alguien me orienta

Comment: No entiendo cual es el problema que tienes... todo parece funcionar bien...

Comment: @KaoX porfa puedes registrar la solucion con tu código, ya que necesito lo mismo y no he podido. gracias